# Javascript, window.event, form validation

Tags: javascript, html

This was an example from our prof and my HTML is rusty so I'm not sure exactly what is going on.
For the form input:

```
<input type="text" name="widgets" id="widgets" size="2" value="0" onchange="calc();" onkeypress="return isNumberInput(this, event);" />
```

For the Javascript:

```
function isNumberInput(field, event)
{
var key, keyChar;
if (window.event)
key = window.event.keyCode;
else if (event)
key = event.which;
else
return true;
// Check for special characters like backspace
if (key == null || key == 0 || key == 8 || key == 13 || key == 27)
return true;
// Check to see if it.s a number
keyChar = String.fromCharCode(key);
if (/\d/.test(keyChar))
{
window.status = "";
return true;
}
else
{
window.status = "Field accepts numbers only.";
return false;
}
```

Can someone explain what is going on?  I'm not too familiar with window.event, event.which, wondow.event.keyCode, etc.  I don't really understand the logic.  TIA!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var key, keyChar; // declare variable to be used
if (window.event) // window.event Microsoft uses window.event. Does it exist? If so continue
    key = window.event.keyCode; // Microsoft uses window.event.keyCode to get the key the was pressed
else if (event) // other modern browsers will create an event object for you to use
    key = event.which; // event.which is the key that was pressed
else // else we can't get to the key maybe this is a full text browser? Anyways, no good exit function
    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this code prevents the user from entering anything except a digit in the text field. The function returns true to allow the user to enter the keystroke, and false to prevent it. Additionally, special characters are allowed through as well.

As far as the part that is confusing you, this is really old code, designed for older versions of Netscape and IE. With modern browsers, you could just use event.keyCode, but Netscape used to use event.which, and IE used to require you to use window.event. Modern browsers hide the status bar too, making the window.status lines useless.